# How to see if map keys contain certain strings?

Tags: string, dictionary, go

Suppose I have a slice of strings like:

```
fruits := {"apple", "orange", "banana"}
```

and a map like

```
box:= map[string]int{
    "chicken": 1,
    "drinks": 4,
    "apples": 42,
}
```

What is the most efficient way to check whether the `box` contains any `apple`, `orange` or `banana`?
Notice that here we seek not exact match but a key that **CONTAINS** certain strings. So simple key search does not work here.

I know I can extract keys from the map:

```
keys := make([]string)
for k := range box {
    keys = append(keys, k)
}
```

And then iterate over both slices to search among the keys:

```
for _, f := range fruits {
  for _, k in keys {
      if strings.Contains(k, f) {
       fmt.Println("Fruit found!")
       }
   }
```

But that refutes the advantage of using map instead of slice for string searchs. So is there better way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to extract the keys:

```
for _, f := range fruits {
  for k,fruit := range box {
      if strings.Contains(k, f) {
       fmt.Printf("Fruit found!: %s",fruit)
       }
   }
}
```

If you only need to check if key exists, you can write `for k := range box`

Since this is a *contains* search, there is no easy way to do it. If it was a *begins with* search, there are other data structures you might want to look at, such as a trie, or prefix-tree. There isn't standard library support for those.